# How do I create a log for results of lftp run in a script

Tags: logfiles

Sorry if this is a simple one to solve. I'm very much and old-newbie and need some hand holding. Please be gentle with me.

I have a shell script that manipulates an image and then uploads it every 5 minutes to my host. It has (mostly) worked without fault for 2 years. The line for lftp looks like this.

```
lftp -e "set net:timeout 20 ; set net:max-retries 4 ; set net:reconnect-interval-base 10 ; put /path/to/file/image.jpg ; exit"  -u username,password,host.com
```

Last night I noticed that many files are not uploading. I suspect that the load on the host is causing the issues.

How do I create a log of failed uploads so that I can give the information to the host for troubleshooting.

Comment: Not only have I never used `lftp`, I've never even heard of it until I read your question. A quick search yielded [this summary](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2018/209/LFTP), summarizing `lftp` in this way: "LFTP, on the other hand, lacks up-to-date documentation." A quick review of the [lftp man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) confirms this, but indicates logging facilities are available. I couldn't quite suss the syntax from a quick read, but suggest you have a look at the man page, and read beginning at `log:enabled`. Let us know how you get on; will look again if you wish.